# How to find the inverse side @OneToOne mappings?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

Let's assume a User can only have on Account. Which side would you make the inverse side?

```
class User {
    @OneToOne(cascade = Cascade.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Account = new Account();
}

class Account {
    @OneToOne
    private User user;
}
```

Would you rather make the `Account` side `mappedBy` so that Account table contains the `User` id, and so that an account is automatically persisted if a new User is created and saved?

`dao.save(new User());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `OneToOne` relationships, the decision for the owning/inverse side has mostly performance implications and thus depends on the answer to the following question:

How will you traverse the relationship in your queries?

If you find yourself writing `User u ... u.account` more often than `Account a ... a.user`, make `User` the owning side.

Just a guess: in most queries that I can imagine, you will be traversing from the user to the related account, so I would place the join column in the User table.